# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "contar" y "decir"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos

Soy un novato absoluto de español, así mi gramática puede contener unos errores (perdón).  ¿Qué verbo debo usar? Sé que los dos se utilizan como "to tell."

Hay ejemplos que utilizan los dos, como:

> Juan me **contó** la historia de cómo su amigo engañó el profesor.
>
> ¡Te **dije** que parases de jugar con los videojuegos!

¿Cuál se utiliza con más frecuencia, y cuál debería utilizarse? Alguna ayuda sería apreciada.

Comment: ¡Muy buena pregunta! Bienvenido a [spanish.se]

Comment: I would answer "contar" means "to tell" and "decir" means "to say"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se usa más el verbo *decir*. El verbo *contar* sólo se usa* cuando una persona le dice a alguien lo que pasó en una historia.

Más ejemplos:

1. Por favor, cuéntame la historia de La Cenicienta.
2. Por favor, dime tu dirección.
3. Mi esposa nunca me dice que me ama.

---

*Además, puede significar "to count".

Comment: Coincido con la respuesta. Como añadido, el DRAE define `contar` como _referir un suceso verdadero o fabuloso_, mientras que la definición de `decir` es mucho más amplia.

Comment: Básicamente sólo "contar" se usa cuando se querer hablar de una historia?

Answer (score 0):

A decir verdad has puesto a trabajar mis neuronas. Soy hispanohablante (nativo) y nunca antes había necesitado establecer la diferencia entre estas dos palabras. Hace días vengo “imaginando” esta respuesta y bueno, aquí te dejo el resultado.

Ambas palabras tienen diversos significados, algunos no se asemejan para nada, pero otros sí. Y es ese el caso en donde ambas palabras, si se quisieran traducir al inglés, podrían traducirse como “to tell”.

Primero, algunos significados particulares (es decir, que no se traducirían con “to tell”) para cada palabra:

**Contar**

**(1)** Numerar o computar cosas. Ej.: “contar las ventanas de un edificio”; “contar los vagones de un tren”;  o simplemente “contar (hasta diez, hasta veinte, etc.).”

Esto se podría traducir como “to count”. En el ejemplo: “to count the windows...”; “to count the wagons...”; “to count (to ten...).”

En los primeros dos ejemplos puede reemplazarse ***count*** por ***enumerate***, y en el tercero por ***recite*** (numbers).

**(2)** Disponer de algo o de alguien, tener confianza sobre algo o alguien. Ej.: “Puedes contar conmigo...”; “Ellos cuentan con que todos nosotros creemos...”

Esto se podría traducir como “to count on”. En el ejemplo: “You can count on me...”; “They count on all of us to create...”

En ambos casos puedes reemplazar ***count*** por ***rely***.

**Decir**

**(1)** Nombrar, llamar. Ej.: “Ellos dijeron mi nombre.”

Esto se podría traducir como “to say”. En el ejemplo: “They said my name.”

**(2)** Dicho de un libro o de un escrito. Ej.: “La escritura dice...”; “El informe dice que...”

Esto también se puede traducir como “to say”. En el ejemplo: “The scripture says...”; “The report says...”

Ahora, esta parte de la respuesta va a ser como un deja-vu de lo que ya te han respondido antes (quizás aclare algo, quizás no). La palabra “**contar**” se utiliza para **relatar** (sinónimo de “contar”) un hecho real o un hecho ficticio. En el primer caso puedes ***contar*** algo que sucedió hace años en un viaje, hace un día en algún bar, o hace media hora mientras te bañabas. En el segundo caso, puedes ***contar*** un chiste o una historia del género que más te guste.

Por otro lado, la palabra “**decir**” se utiliza para expresar algo, un pensamiento, un sentimiento, una opinión, entre otros. Puedes ***decirle*** a alguien que se ve lindo con lo que trae puesto, puedes ***decirle*** a alguien que lo quieres mucho (o que no lo quieres en absoluto), puedes ***decir*** que tienes frío, puedes ***decir*** “ay”, “ey”, “a” (palabras al azar), puedes ***decir*** cosas sin sentido, etc.

Lo cierto es que, si bien podemos establecer estas reglas, hay casos en los que necesitarás utilizar una especie de criterio personal para elegir la palabra correcta, y eso te lo dará la experiencia.

Espero haberte ayudado.